# Is it possible to modify an attribute's attribute via reference?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

Let's say I have a `Language` class and a `Director` class.

```
class Language
{
private:
    std::string name;
    Director director;
public:
    Language(std::string name);
    std::string getName() { return this->name; };
    Director& getDirector() { return this->director; };
    void setDirector(const Director& director) { this->director = director; };
}

class Director
{
private:
    std::string main_language;
public:
    Director();
    std::string getMainLanguage() { return this->main_language; };
    void setMainlanguage(std::string language) { this->main_language = language; };
}
```

There is a one-to-one relationship between both classes, `Language` stores a `Director` object whereas `Director` only stores the name of the `Language` as a string. 
 
Now, if I do this:

```
Language language("English");
Director director;

language.setDirector(director);
language.getDirector().setMainLanguage(language.getName());
```

The `director` attribute of `language` do get modified but the original `director` do not. I thought using references in both getter and setter of `Language` would have worked but apparently not. Obviously, I could just use `director.setMainLanguage()` but that's not what I'd like. 
Is there any reason this happens or should I just try another way of achieving this?

Comment: *"I thought using references in both getter and setter of Language would have worked but apparently not."* -- using a reference in the getter *did* work since this code modified the `director` member of `language`. It's only the setter that does not work the way you thought it would (it does not link the local variable to the member).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this function:

```
void setDirector(const Director& director) { this->director = director; };
```

even though you are accepting the `Director` by reference, you are making a copy in the body, so you end up not changing the original `Director` argument.

You could make the `director` member a `Director&`, but then you *have* to initialize this reference in a constructor of `Language`.  e.g:

```
class Language
{
private:
    std::string name;
    Director &director;
public:
    Language(std::string name, Director &d) : director(d), name(name) {}
// ...
}
```

and call it like this:

```
Director director;
Language language("English", director);
```

You could make the `director` member a `Director *` as well. You would have to change the syntax of `GetDirector` though, and make sure that the pointer never dangles, by ensuring that the passed in `Director` lives as long as the `Language` object.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the constructor because there are other classes involved as well.. Using pointers looks like a good idea but I think it will get too complex. I will use an `int id` as an attribute for `director` and try to work things out.

Comment: I agree about the pointers getting complex. An `id` field seems reasonable. Good luck :)